# R integration in Tableau Online v9

Tags: r, tableau-api

I'm a trying to publish my tableau 9 workbook into tableau online.

The problem is that I have integrated some R script in my workbook. It's working fine on my desktop and I have install Rserve.

When I try to publish (on tableau online) it return this error:

```
An unexpected error occurred. If you continue to receive this error please contact your Tableau Server Administrator.
TableauException: No Rserve connection configured.
```

Do you know how we can make it work with tableau Online (not server)

Comment: I *really* think the community will need more than "An unexpected error occurred" to assist you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R connections are not supported in Tableau Public and Tableau Online. Reference the R implementations notes at http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/r-implementation-notes.